# how do I enter multiple keys in textbox to validate between two numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with text box in it and I have given two numbers as min number and max number. For example if I set the min number to 9 and max to 40 then it is only validating for the first digit.

```js
function checkLength_lc(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = "Min 9 and Max 40";
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 9) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min value is 9";
    document.getElementById("LC_text").value = 9;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 40) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Max value is 40";
    document.getElementById("LC_text").value = 40;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min 9 and Max 40";
   isValidLC=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}
function focusfunc() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = 'Min 9 and Max 40';
}
function blurfunc() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = ' ';
}
function checkButtonValidation(){
if(isValidLC==false){
document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}else{
   document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="lowercase">
<label class="heading">Minimum number of Lowercase</label>
<input type="number" id="LC_text" onclick="checkLength_lc(this)" onkeyup="checkLength_lc(this)" onfocus="focusfunc()" onblur="blurfunc()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg4"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="btn" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```

So, In the above example, the is 0 and 40 but if I want to type 30 (which is a valid number) is not allowing to type. The moment I press "3", it will get changed to "0". How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function checkLength_lc(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = "Min 9 and Max 40";
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 9) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min value is 9";
    //document.getElementById("LC_text").value = 9;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 40) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Max value is 40";
    //document.getElementById("LC_text").value = 40;
    isValidLC=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min 9 and Max 40";
   isValidLC=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}
function focusfunc() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = 'Min 9 and Max 40';
}
function blurfunc() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = ' ';
}
function checkButtonValidation(){
if(isValidLC==false){
document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}else{
   document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="lowercase">
<label class="heading">Minimum number of Lowercase</label>
<input type="number" id="LC_text" onclick="checkLength_lc(this)" onkeyup="checkLength_lc(this)" onfocus="focusfunc()" onblur="blurfunc()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg4"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="btn" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```

you no need to enter the value after checking the conditions just stop from commit

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the input value as the user is typing (which isn't so user-friendly and can also lead to difficulties like this), you might consider simply disabling the button while the text isn't valid:

```js
function checkLength_lc(elem) {
  const msg4 = document.getElementById("msg4");
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  if (elem.value == '') {
    msg4.innerHTML = "Min 9 and Max 40";
    msg4.style.color = 'black';
    btn.disabled = true;
  } else if (elem.value < 9) {
    msg4.style.color = 'red';
    msg4.innerHTML = "Min value is 9";
    btn.disabled = true;
  } else if (elem.value > 40) {
    msg4.style.color = 'red';
    msg4.innerHTML = "Max value is 40";
    btn.disabled = true;
  } else {
    msg4.style.color = 'green';
    msg4.innerHTML = "Min 9 and Max 40";
    btn.disabled = false;
  }
}

function focusfunc() {
  document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = 'Min 9 and Max 40';
}

function blurfunc() {
  document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = ' ';
}

function checkButtonValidation() {
  if (isValidLC == false) {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="lowercase">
  <label class="heading">Minimum number of Lowercase</label>
  <input type="number" id="LC_text" onclick="checkLength_lc(this)" onkeyup="checkLength_lc(this)" onfocus="focusfunc()" onblur="blurfunc()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg4"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="btn" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```

If you *have* to change the value while the user is typing, another option would be to do so only after a debounce (eg, if not valid, only change the value after the user has stopped typing for 2 seconds, or something like that - giving them some time to finish typing).

Comment: But I want that to be there coz I dont want to enter out of range values. So that if I give out of range values it will automatically should set to nearest range value.

Comment: If you don't want there to *ever* be out-of-range values in the input, then users won't be able to type numbers which may eventually become permissible in-range values - which is exactly the problem you're facing in the question.